# Python: Calculate mean and sd of normal distribution in intervall

Tags: python, normal-distribution

my question is:

I have an intervall/multiple intervals, lets say:

`[0;0.3]
[0.3;0,8]
[0.8;1]`

In every interval I have a normal distribution, sampled with 
`truncnorm() and .rvs()`.

So I have multiple "normal distributions" on the x-axis.

But the truncnorm-method expects the mean and the sd of the distribution within the intervall. How can I calculate the mean and the sd of an specific interval in python???

`numpy.mean()` f.e. doesnt seem to work. And I get strange results, so I think that my mean/sd is calculated wrong before I execute the truncnorm.

Thanks guys

*Edit: For other columns, where the intervalls are not as small, it works fine. Is there a limit of how small the Intervall can be? The Error occurs f.e. in an intervall from

[0,12;0,17]--> Value 0,0937818650369 (out of range)*

Yeah sure.
What I want to do is: I have an Intervall, sample me one Value, which is between the boarder of that intervall and simple it in a way of truncated normal distribution. I have an extra column and it should write the value I gain by sampling in another column.
For example: Intervall [0.2;0.6] --> sample value 0.343433
I think I found a solution:

```
truncnorm().stats()
```

But I don't know why, but for the parameters I give the

```
truncnorm()
```

function, almost 50% of the values I gain are outside the boarders. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code (a short part of the code)

```
      convert_cat=(name_convert_column,name_convert_column,_tabelle,name_convert_column,_tabelle,_tabelle,name_convert_column)
    drop_view=(name_convert_column)
    calculate=(name_convert_column,name_convert_column,name_convert_column,name_convert_column,name_convert_column,_tabelle,name_convert_column,name_convert_column)
    cur.execute("CREATE VIEW convert_cat_%s (quotient, %s, rnum) AS SELECT (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s ) ) as quotient, %s, row_number() over ( order by (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s ) ) desc ) as rnum FROM     %s  GROUP BY %s ORDER BY quotient desc" %convert_cat)
    cur.execute("Select b.ID,a.unten,a.oben, a.mean, a.sd FROM( SELECT t3.RNUM, t3.%s, lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc) as unten , t3.com_PR as oben, ((t3.com_PR +(lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc)))/2) as MEAN, ((t3.com_PR-(lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc)))/6) AS SD FROM( SELECT t1.rnum, t1.%s , SUM(t2.quotient) as com_Pr FROM CONVERT_CAT_%s t1 INNER JOIN CONVERT_CAT_%s t2 ON t1.rnum >= t2.rnum group by t1.rnum, t1.%s, t1.quotient ORDER BY RNUM asc ) t3) a INNER JOIN %s b ON b.%s = a.%s order by ID asc" %calculate)
    _content_category = cur.fetchall()
    add_category_number_column = (_tabelle, name_convert_column)
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE %s ADD %s_category NUMBER(15,14)" % add_category_number_column)
    x=0
    for ID in _content_category:
        id = _content_category[0]
        id_category = [j[0] for j in _content_category]
        unten_category = [j[1] for j in _content_category]
        oben_category = [j[2] for j in _content_category]
        #mean_category = [j[3] for j in _content_category]
        sd_category = [j[4] for j in _content_category]
        mean, var = truncnorm.stats(unten_category[x], oben_category[x], moments='mv')
       # sd = np.sqrt(var)
        X = get_truncated_normal(mean= mean, sd=sd_category[x], low=unten_category[x], upp=oben_category[x])
        update_cells_value = float(X.rvs(1))
        category = (_tabelle, name_convert_column,update_cells_value,id_category[x])
     cur.execute("UPDATE %s SET %s_category = %s WHERE ID=%s" % category)

        x += 1
```

I tried to calculate mean and sd in the sql query with

```
1) ((t3.com_PR +(lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc)))/2) as MEAN
 2) ((t3.com_PR-(lag(t3.com_Pr,1,0) OVER (order by rnum asc)))/6) AS SD
```

and with 
`truncnorm().stats()` function. Seems that with the stats function, the result are getting even worse and the values are even more out of range then before...

Comment: Can you share some minimal code to your problem?

Comment: I did :) Its in the initial post now...

Answer (score 0):

Despite I cannot run your example, one possible problem:

```
 for ID in _content_category:
    id = _content_category[0]
    ...
```

might better be:

```
 for ID in _content_category:
    id = _content_category[ID]
    ...
```